# Why are non-Muslims at a disadvantage by birth? Why will Muslims ultimately go to heaven, even if they don't research and follow God's commands?

Tags: non-muslim, jahannam, justice

Why is there facilitation for a child born in a Muslim Family as compared to a child born in a Non-Muslim Family? Why is struggle for a Muslim person born in a Muslim Family made easier as compared to a Non-Muslim person born in a Non-Muslim Family?

I understand that everyone should seek the truth and that everyone is born in the state of fitra (nature) ie he's born a Muslim and later on, his family influences him to shape his religious and ideological beliefs. However, if a person is born in a Muslim family, he is at an advantage compared to an individual who is born in a non-Muslim family since the person born in Muslim family already knows that God is one and about the finality of Prophethood. So even if he doesn't do research or seek truth, he'll die as a Muslim (even if he doesn't obey God's commands) and therefore, he'll ultimately go to heaven after some time in hell. Whereas the person born in a non-Muslim family, even if he commits good deeds, will not enter heaven if he's a polytheist or an athiest. So why are some people at such a massive advantage when it comes to be born in a certain Muslim family? And how did God decide that which individuals deserve to be born in a Muslim family and the others don't? Did all the people before getting born underwent any test? And if there wasn't then isn't God unjust in doing so by creating unfavourable circumstances for one group of people?

I've heard replies from scholars like Zakir Naik and others on this topic but those seemed unconvincing so I thought this is right forum.

Edit: Why is this being down voted? Is asking questions not a part of Islam?

P.S. I'm a Muslim myself

Comment: Who claims that there's a disadvantage.

Comment: Though you have a good question posted here, I'd recommend you to first try to understand the concept of Qadr (PreDestination) from a scholar in your masjid or madrasa. Without understanding the fundamentals it is futile to analyze more complicated aspects of Islam on a website where you get answers from random folks not all if whom may be qualified to answer accurately in light of Quran and Hadiths. Also note the concept of Qadr itself is quite deep and needs a patient mind to grasp it.

Comment: @Ahmed I already understand the concept of predestination. Why are you assuming that I don't know it?

Comment: @lookatmenow With all due respect, your question implicitly implies that.

Comment: @Ahmed You could have explained a bit or provided a link that explains it, instead of saying that the question implies it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not only does it lack focus, asking multiple questions at once, there's also no indication of what you're even looking for in an answer; you claim to have researched this already and rejected existing explanations with no reasoning as to why, all you're likely to get here, as-written, is more of the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt. What convincing for me was below knowledge.
Who go to heaven, Who go to hell. the decision is only with Allah. Only Allah decides who goes where. i.e., A person born as a Muslim doesn't mean he will go to heaven and vise versa.

Allah said,

> فَمَن يَعْمَلْ مِثْقَالَ ذَرَّةٍ خَيْرًا يَرَهُ – So whoever does an atom’s weight of good will see it,

> وَمَن يَعْمَلْ مِثْقَالَ ذَرَّةٍ شَرًّا يَرَهُ – And whoever does an atom’s weight of evil will see it.

There is no mention of Muslim or Non Muslim.
Remember the word **Nafsi Nafsi Nafsiya**. Even prophets will say, I'm not sure about my self. They will run away from their own child.

Everywhere Allah mentioned people goes to hell, from my limited understanding Allah mention who goes there. Almost all those time, it was about the worst humans. It was for people like,

1. Those who knows the truth but ignored it out of arrogance.
2. Those who do wrong to others etc.

Also note that Allah will forgive all except Kufur. But for those who don't know Allah is one and only worthy for prayer, Or never had a chance to face with the truth, They won't be blamed for what they don't know. Because Allah is just.

So, If a person born in Non Muslim family, it doesn't mean that person belongs to Hell, and vice versa.

Comment: [Quran 3:85] And whoever desires other than Islam as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.

Answer (score 0):

Allah guide whom he wills.

> "Surely you do not guide whomever you love, but Allah guides whomever
> He decides, and He knows best the ones (who are) rightly-guided."
> (Translation by Dr. Ghali)

Qur'an 28:56

Did you know, there's someone who was born in a Muslim household and become an atheist/agnostic/other religions? and did you know, there's someone who was born in an atheist/agnostic/other religions household and become a Muslim? Surely, Allah is the turner of the hearts.

> "... Thus does Allah lead into error whomever He decides, and He
> guides whomever He decides, ..." (Translation by Dr.Ghali)

Qur'an 74:31

> Abdullah b. Amr b. al-'As reported that he heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
> as saying:
>
> Verily, the hearts of all the sons of Adam are between the two fingers
> out of the fingers of the Compassionate Lord as one heart. He turns
> that to any (direction) He likes. Then Allahs Messenger (ﷺ) said: 0
> Allah, the Turner of the hearts, turn our hearts to Thine obedience.

[Muslim 2655](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2655)

Conclusion: Although it may look like they have an upper hand to be born in a muslim family, in the end it doesn't matter. What matters is what they believe in the end.

> "O you have believed, be pious to Allah with His true piety, and
> definitely do not die except as Muslims." (Translation by Dr. Ghali)

Qur'an 3:102

What about the non-muslims which news never reached to them?

I advise you to read [this](https://whatisquran.com/877-the-condition-of-people-who-doesnt-know-about-islam.html)

(I'm really sorry for my comments under my answer, i've deleted it. i just realized it resembles Qadariyyah. In islam, everything is already written in Lauhul Mahfudz and there's fate.)

and Allah knows best.

Comment: If Allah leads into error whomever He decides, and He guides whomever He decides then how can a person be held accountable for the religion he practiced since he can say that Allah didn't turn his heart or Allah didn't guide him. And secondly, you said "Did you know, there's someone who was born in a Muslim household and become an atheist/agnostic/other religions? and did you know, there's someone who was born in an atheist/agnostic/other religions household and become a Muslim?" Then you should also know that there are millions of Muslims by birth who don't convert into any other religion.

Comment: It is a massive advantage for people born in Muslim families since even if they don't research or seek the truth and they don't obey God's commands, they'll still die as Muslims and ultimately, go to heaven whereas this isn't the same for Non-Muslims. If a non-Muslim person doesn't convert into Muslim, he'll stay in the hellfire forever.

Comment: You won't find a single person who left Islam or converted to Islam "BY THEIR OWN FREE WILL", between 8th to 17th century! What you are saying is only applicable to 21st century where we have hundreds of thousands of Muslim leaving Islam etc! Take England for example, the first English convert was in 18th century! Similarly, I don't know of any Turk who left Islam pre 19th century but look at them now! Same is the case with Iran and South Asia and even Middle East! And the verses you've posted are not generic but specific to 7th century